# How to pass request headers from integration to my webhook service through dialogflow API service?

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es

Below is the flow diagram from https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/fulfillment-overview

[image]

How to pass request headers from custom chatbot client (integration [2]) to my webhook service[5] through dialogflow API service [4].

I use the RPC call to send the user query (text entered by user in chatbot) to DF API service:

```
      const dfResponses = await sessionsClient.detectIntent(queryRequest);
      responseBody = dfResponses[0].queryResult;
```

`queryRequest` has below structure:

```
  const queryRequest = {
    session: sessionPath,
    queryInput: {
      text: {
        text: queryText,
        languageCode,
      },
    },
  };
```

I don't see a way through which I can pass headers to my webhook service from by chatbot widget.

Thanks in advance! :)

**UPDATE:**
Based on the below comment by @Prissoner, I am now trying to pass my auth token to my webhook through `queryParams.payload`
So now my `queryRequest` is like below:

```
    session: sessionPath,
    queryInput: {
      text: {
        text: queryText,
        languageCode,
      },
    },
    queryParams: {
      payload: {
        authToken
      }
    },
  };
```

On calling `sessionsClient.detectIntent(queryRequest)`, I expect `request.originalDetectIntentRequest.payload` to have the `authToken` in the webhook request. But then `request.originalDetectIntentRequest.payload` is an empty object.

Comment: Why, specifically, do you need the headers? Or are you just trying to send additional information to the webhook?

Comment: I am trying to send across ```jwt token``` through ```Authorization``` header. I want to control the information that the webHook sends back as response based on whether the user is logged in or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't include this as part of the header from Dialogflow to your webhook.

You can, however, include this data in the [queryParameters](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/reference/rest/v2/QueryParameters) that you include as part of the detect intent call. You have a couple of options where to put them:

1. The `payload` field contains an arbitrary object structure, so you can put whatever you want here in pretty much any format.
2. As one of the `contexts` (specifically as a context parameter). This is a little more rigid, but might be easier to manage and fetch the values in some cases.

Comment: Hey thanks! But then I tried passing the sessionsClient.detectIntent(queryRequest) method with ```queryRequest = {session, queryInput : { text: {text, languageCode} }, queryParams: { payload: { authToken }} }```. In the webHook Request, I get the queryText, but ```originalDetectIntentRequest.payload``` is an empty object. Where am I wrong?

Comment: If you're having problems with it, I'd suggest you update your question with details of what you're trying, or asking this as a new question (again, showing as many details as you can). Trying to show code in comments is difficult.

Answer (score 0):

You can  set webhook headers using `webhookHeaders()` of the [queryParams](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/reference/rest/v2/QueryParameters) object.

```json
"queryParams": {   
        "webhookHeaders":{
            "Authorization": "Bearer {{access_token}}"
        }
    }
```

You can pass custom payload using [originalDetectIntentRequest](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/fulfillment-webhook/#webhook_request)